# Angular not loading API - First App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginning in the world of AngularJS.

I have created a small app which should pull data from an API with some dummy values. The API works and gives the following JSON(typing /api/employees/):

```
[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"George","LastName":"Lucas"},{"Id":2,"FirstName":"Peter","LastName":"Jackson"},{"Id":3,"FirstName":"Christopher","LastName":"Nolan"}]
```

To consume this I have created the following:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

angular.module('empApp', [
'ngRoute', 'employeesServices'
]).config(config);

function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/test.html',
        controller: 'TestCtrl'
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/Views/list.html',
        cntroller:'EmployeeListController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

angular.module('empApp')
    .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);


// Test Contoller - ngView
TestCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        message: "This is my app!!!"
    };
};

// Employee List Controller
EmployeeListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Employee'];

function EmployeeListController($scope, Employee) {
    $scope.employees = Employee.query();
};

// Employees Service
angular
    .module('employeesServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Employee', Employee);

Employee.$inject = ['$resource'];

function Employee($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/employees/:id');
};})();
```

I haven't seprated the code into separate files at this time but do intend to. Please also give any advice re naming conventions etc any help is appreciated

I have the following partial html file:

```
<div>
<h1>List Employees</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
            <td>
                <a href="/employees/edit/{{emp.Id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">edit</a>
                <a href="/employees/delete/{{emp.Id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">delete</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{emp.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{emp.LastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <a href="/employees/add" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Employee</a>
</p></div>
```

the index.html file contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="empApp">
       <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
       </head>
           <body>
               <h1>Hello Angular JS</h1>

What is 2+2 ?
<br /><br />
Answer = {{2+2}}
<br /><br />
<ng-view></ng-view>
             </body>
     </html>
```

Angular works as the expression confirms a 4. But I get no data from the API.
Please help!!

Comment: It appears from using the developer tools I get the following error:

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'EmployeeListController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/ng/areq?p0=EmployeeListController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have a typo in the routes definition( `cntroller:'EmployeeListController'`). 
(and I don't have enough reputation for comments)

Comment: many thanks for noticing the typo, but nope nothing changes still no data

Answer (score 0):

Exact. Probably your EmployeeListController was never instantiated by wrong declaration "cntroller" and your employees variable have undefined value.

Comment: many thanks for noticing the typo, but nope nothing changes still no data

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of reading and web pages I realised that I had not defined the controller as available to the module so my code should read:

```
angular.module('empApp')
    .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl)
    .controller('EmployeeListController', EmployeeListController);
```

Thanks for looking!